# zk + Spring 4 + preauthentication with webseal

Tags: java, spring, zk, webseal

First sorry for my english, My problem that when try configure a Spring Filter with webseal, I can get from header the "iv-user" with my user information (I only need this), but when redirect to a internal url, my navegator shows "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", maybe my configurations is bad

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <description>My Project Application</description>
  <display-name>my-project-web</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <listener>
    <display-name>Spring Context Loader</display-name>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>appFormacionFilterSesion</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>appFormacionFilterSesion</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <listener>
    <description>ZK listener for session cleanup</description>
    <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <description>ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
      <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description>The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dspLoader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.InterpreterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dspLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.dsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>appformacionwb/zkau/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>doc</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-word</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>gif</extension>
    <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>htm</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>html</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>jpeg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>jpg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>txt</extension>
    <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>xls</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>xml</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>zhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>zul</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My filter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class AppFormacionFilter implements Filter {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppFormacionFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {


        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            if(req.getHeader("iv-user")==null){
                log.info("El usuario ingresado es vacio ");
            }else{
                log.info("El usuario que ingreso "+req.getHeader("iv-user"));

                req.getSession().setAttribute("username", req.getHeader("iv-user"));
                req.getSession().setAttribute("urlRedirect", req.getHeader("referer"));

                String uriReqURI = req.getHeader("Cookie");

                String[] uriArray = StringUtils.split(uriReqURI, ";");

                if(uriArray.length>0){
                    req.getSession().setAttribute("url", uriArray[0]);
                    log.info(uriArray[0]);
                }

            }

            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect("/someUrl.zul");

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Please, Maybe some example ?, thanks for all...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The filter `appFormacionFilterSesion` is configured to run on any path `/*`, it means that when the path `httpResponse.sendRedirect("/someUrl.zul")` is executed your filter code is called again. Maybe you need to add the `req.getSession().getAttribute("username") != null` to your main condition.

Comment: Thanks Damian..!!!, the URL is redirect correctly , but don't show the page (is empty), but when change the redirect by chain.doFilter..., the junction (webseal) is lost, so the page is losted.

Comment: For example:
* http://someurl/junction/contextroot/index.zul  then redirect to
  http://someurl/contextroot/zul/somepage.zul